# Is Kerdi membrane supposed to be easily torn off from the thinset?

Tags: shower, kerdi

I’m a first time DIYer and I’m testing and learning Kerdi membrane for my bathroom remodeling. Last night I used the membrane with Kerdi’s own thinset(the Allset) and on a drywall. Today the thinset is dry but I found I can tear it down easily by hand. Is this how Kerdi membrane supposed to be? I’m worrying because I will put wall tiles on top of the membrane and I imagine the tiles probably heavier than how much force I torn down my testing membrane. Can the tiles be too heavy and the membrane got torn away from the drywall? Thank you!!!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine according to a [Schluter FAQ](https://www.schluter.com/schluter-us/en_US/faq/shower-system-kerdi-membrane-bond-strength),

> I installed my Schluter™-KERDI membrane yesterday. Why is it so easy to peel it off the wall today?
>
> Thin-set mortar takes time to cure. The bond strength will increase over the first week and month after installation. However, there is sufficient bond strength immediately after installation to support the tile covering.